# Task scheduler (Windows) for python code not executing, showing (0*1) error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-task-scheduler

*It works with test.py showing simple print statement*

**BUT not working for below code, how to have this below code executed through scheduler**

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('+91xxxxxxxxx', 'Good Morning', 18, 18)
```

Comment: Is this working outside of task scheduler?

Comment: yes it is working. I can execute this from Spyder console, which opens browser (whatsapp) and send the message

Comment: This is most likely related to how the task is set up. `Run only when user is logged on` probably needs to be checked. `Program/script` should be the path to the python executable. `add arguments` should be your python script and `Start in` should be the path your folder resides in.

Comment: I have all this option checked. I can run my another program (game) through task scheduler but not this 2 line code program. It opens and in split second action started and says action completed. Not sure external browser that it has to open is the issue..

Comment: You could run it with the `-i` option. So, `-i my_script.py`. This will leave the interpreter open after an error in your script occurs or your program ends to help you debug. Either that or have it dump the logging to a file somewhere.

Comment: "-i stest.py" - This makes my error count 0*2

Comment: it is giving error for programs referencing files outside and if it happens to open a browser. Other programs just with for loops and print statement working fine

Comment: Out of curiosity can you run this from command line?

Comment: how to run from command prompt? when running should I be in the path where program resides when running

Comment: Yes. The command should be `"Path\to\python.exe" "my_script.py"`. Where `Path\to\python.exe` is the path to your python executable.